# react update state with Mongo DB data change

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, state

i am building a bank project
using React js, Node js , Mongo DB
and i have a little issue
i need to update the users state at everytime i change data on my mongo db
you can see at the code i upload that i have a few function that change something in the data base
like "loanMoney,TransferMoney" and its update correctly
i using the users state that contain all the data on my mongo DB
but when i change something its not update the state correctly
so no i using set interval that every 2 second it will update the state and its work
but i know its not the right way to update the state every update to my dataBase
please guide me to the correct way

```
import { useContext, createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
export const DataContext = createContext();
export const useDataProvider = () => {
  return useContext(DataContext);
};

const DataProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const baseUrl = "http://localhost:5000/bank";
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      axios.get(baseUrl).then((response) => {
        setUsers(response.data);
      });
    }, 2000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  const addUser = (data) => {
    const user = { ...data, balance: 5000, expense: [] };
    axios.post(`${baseUrl}/sign-up`, user).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data[0]);
    });
  };
  const changeLanguage = (value) => {
    return t(value);
  };
  const specificUser = (username, password) => {
    const check = users.find((user) => {
      return user.username === username && user.password === password;
    });
    return check;
  };


  const duplicateUsers = (username) => {
    const check = users.find((user) => {
      return user.username === username;
    });
    return check;
  };

  const transferMoney = (username, price, usernameToTransfer) => {
    const details = { username, price, usernameToTransfer };
    axios.post(`${baseUrl}/user/transfer-money`, details);
  };
  const loanMoney = (username, price) => {
    const user = { username, price };
    axios.post(`${baseUrl}/user/loan`, user);
  };

  const value = {
    users,
    setUsers,
    addUser,
    specificUser,
    transferMoney,
    changeLanguage,
    isUserExist,
    duplicateUsers,
    loanMoney,
  };
  return <DataContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</DataContext.Provider>;
};
export default DataProvider;
```

Comment: You can use the `setUsers` state setter to update the users state variable, right after the axios command has finished its execution in loanMoney and transferMoney. After that, the consumers of DataContext.Provider will automatically be notified about the changes and will update (re-render).

Comment: I think i didnt understand you correctly you mean that on the end of the function of loanMoney,transfer money i will make a set users and change it? Because i want that the use effect will change the users from the data base and if i understand you you mean that i need to repeat myself and change it again with the functions

Comment: You can get rid of the useEffect. If you want the users to be updated everytime the loanMoney or transferMoney gets executed, just call setUsers after the axios request. No need for useEffect. And, you can of course, run the code that right now is in the useEffect, at the end of the loanMoney/transferMoney functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on interval as it's unreliable and costly for no values, but you already made that point by yourself so:

As far as I'm aware there are 3 possibilities (from best to worst):

- instead of fetching the users in the DB on an interval basis, you put a listener on the collection (I'm not fluent enough with Mongo syntax but it should look like that:)

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const stream = mongodb.collection.watch(pipeline); // initialize the stream, take a look at the doc for the pipeline part
        stream.on("change", (changeEvent) => {
          /** this add a listener to the collection, any change will fire this function */
          /** iterate over changeEvent to find updated users */
          /** you'll want to concat unchanged users from users state and the result of that iteration */
          setUsers(result)
        });
        return () => stream.close();  // correctly close the listener when the component is unmounted
    }, [])
```

It will correctly be fired whenever the DB is updated with the changes, regardless of who trigger the changes and where, which is usually the optimal solution considering that your bank use case require synchronicity, but that's the one requiring the more work.

- the easier and "a bit less sync" option is to create a function that fetch your users just once (the same you have, minus the interval), and catch axios responses (like you did in addUser to console.log the response) to fire the fetch function again on callback

```
const fetchUsers = () => axios.get(baseUrl).then((response) => {
   setUsers(response.data);
});

const transferMoney = (username, price, usernameToTransfer) => {
   const details = { username, price, usernameToTransfer };
   axios.post(`${baseUrl}/user/transfer-money`, details)
     .then((res) => fetchUsers());
};

useEffect(() => fetchUsers(), []); // so it's still fetched at least once
```

It means you'll only get updated if you refresh or make a change, but you'll be updated with all changes, even ones made by someone else.

- last one, you could simply read the axios response when posting something and update the users with only the change in this response, but it will increase the odds of asynchrony between users as everyone will only be updated with their own changes

Comment: ok i get it for now i will choose the second approch but tomorrow i will learn about the first one because like you said this one is the best approch. the second approch also work perfectly! thank you and i have a little question i hope you will help me i want the inital state of the users will get the data from Mongo DB so i try to make a function using axios.get and return the data but i dont get it so what i need is use axios get and this time not make setUsers to the response.data now i need to return it because i want the first inital of users will get it and not empty array